# How to fix or set the label height and width with respect to GridPane row height and column width by using JavaFX and Scene Builder?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, scenebuilder

How to set height and width of the `Label` with respect to `GridPane` row height and column width?

Please check my below images

this image is minimized screen
[image: this one is my minimized screen image]

this one is maximized screen
[image: This one is my maximized screen image]

this image is my label layout properties
[image: This are my label layout properties]

I want to resize the `Label` with respect to `GridPane` row height and column width.

Through code I am setting the background color for the label like below.

```
if(cmnd1.WIM.equals("Y")){
   javafx.application.Platform.runLater( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            lsduController1.oneWIM.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image("/images/Wim_T.png")));
            lsduController1.oneWIM.setStyle("-fx-background-color: none;");
        }
   });
} else {
    javafx.application.Platform.runLater( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            lsduController1.oneWIM.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image("/images/Wim_F.png")));
            lsduController1.oneWIM.setStyle("-fx-background-color: Red;");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is setting the `maxHeight` and `maxSize` to `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`.

Use `MAX_VALUE` instead

```xml
<Label style="-fx-background-color: red;" text="Label">
    <maxHeight>
        <Double fx:constant="MAX_VALUE"/>
    </maxHeight>
    <maxWidth>
        <Double fx:constant="MAX_VALUE"/>
    </maxWidth>
</Label>
```

(This should be available from the dropdown in SceneBuilder too.)

To resize the `ImageView` too, bind the `fitWidth` and `fitHeight` properties to the label size. E.g.:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image("/images/Wim_F.png"));
imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(lsduController1.oneWIM.widthProperty().subtract(10d));
imageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(lsduController1.oneWIM.heightProperty().subtract(10d));
lsduController1.oneWIM.setGraphic(imageView);
```

Comment: still now i have the same problem @fabian

Comment: still now i have the same problem,i modified like" Max Width:MAX_VALUE" and  " Max Height:MAX_VALUE" and in pre view it showing fine when i run the application, so images will be present there so is there any effect with images, please give me sujestion - @fabian

Comment: give me suggestion for above comment - @fabian

Comment: thank's for your reply , how can i do please provide some example code or syntax -@fabian